# ”:ENCODING/HEX: ODD LENGTH HEX STRING” error sending ETH [will pay 1 ETH bounty]

Tags: ether, wallets

When I try to send Ether I get an error code that says:`ENCODING/HEX: ODD LENGTH HEX STRING`. Here the history, my PC had had issues working properly so I did a system recovery, then rebooted Mist wallet and recovered my keystore. However I have one issue I am concerned with that might be affecting it, I didn't save my keystore on a drive, instead, I printed it on paper (weird I know) and retyped the text character for character as it was on my printed copy of the original keystore. Now I can't send Ether or tokens but I can receive them with no problems.

```
Version: 0.9.0
OS & Version: osx
Node type: geth 1.6.6
Full Sync
```

My console is reading:

```
12consoleLogCapture.js:44 Unhandled rejection VersionError: The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (2). @ file:///Applications/Ethereum%20Wallet.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/interface/wallet/3e2c5ebd8efbf7fc573dced0138d300ec5a4bff9.js:212:20967)
consoleLogCapture.js:44 Node started syncing, stopping app operation @ file:///Applications/Ethereum%20Wallet.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/interface/wallet/3e2c5ebd8efbf7fc573dced0138d300ec5a4bff9.js:372:601
file:///Applications/Ethereum%20Wallet.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/inte…/wallet/packages/ethereum_dapp-styles/fonts/SourceSansPro-ExtraLightIt.otf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///sockjs/info?cb=k2g5d5vryg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
3e2c5eb….js:416 renderAccountPage: 56.296ms
3e2c5eb….js:416 renderAccountPage: 26.191ms
```

[image: Screenshot of the sending error of Mist:]

Comment: You have not added the screenshot here. It looks like a path of the file on your machine. Try uploading again please.

Comment: It appears your file with the private key is corrupted, or you have typed a wrong character.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of mew? Have you tried updating it?

Comment: Did you make sure your private key was 64 characters long ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the private key (on paper or elsewhere) then you're probably okay. I am not an expert on reading the console message (is anyone?), but it **does not** appear to be a problem with your key. (If it is, that is literally the worst error message I've ever seen.) My guess is that there is something messed up with either your installation of geth or your machine.

It make sense that you can receive ether into the account as that does not require you to have the private key. If I send ether to your public address it will show up even if the account is inaccessible due to a lost key.

The trouble is you want to be able to send ether **from** your account. For this, you need your private key (the thing you typed in from the paper).

You can test that you have a valid private key by using it with myetherwallet (do not search Google--there are scam addresses that look very similar and will steal your transaction). With myetherwallet and the correct private key and password, you should be able to send money out of the address. Send a very small amount of ether first as a test.

If you can send ether, the problem is definitely with your installation of geth, or Mist, or both, or you have some other problem on your machine.

If you can't send ether with myetherwallet because it says something about a wrong password or incorrect private key, then the problem is with your piece of paper.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot even add the keystone to MYETHERWALLET, it will not allow it and an error message pops up that says"TypeError: Invalid hex string"